# Getting errors while using Backgroundworkers

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I am making dynamic dashboard and that's why all datagrids and datacharts should use background workers. Because sometimes getting data from the database takes 5-10 seconds and meanwhile application freezes if i don't use background workers. So using background workers are must for me.

If i don't use background workers i don't get any errors. 
However when i use background workers in different times (sometimes in 5 mins, sometimes after 1 hour) i get following errors;

```
1-) System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added
2-) object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I don't know the reason for this. As i stated, If i don't use background workers, Everything works fine.

Here is the example code on the chart and usage of the backgroundworkers.

```
public void getTopSQL()

{
    dtTopSQL.Clear();
    odaTopSQL = new OracleDataAdapter(getTopSQLDetails, oradb);
    odaTopSQL.Fill(dtTopSQL);
    dtCurTopSQL.Merge(dtTopSQL); // Get current values from datatable dtTopSQL and add rows to general datatable 'dtCurTopSQL'

        if (dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable().Any() == true) // check for if datatable is not empty
        {
            maxDate = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable().Max(z => z.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"));
            minDate = maxDate.AddSeconds(-90);
        }



        var isFull = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable()  // check for if datatable is not empty
          .Where(l => l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") >= minDate && l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") <= maxDate).Any();



        if (isFull == true) // Here the magic happens.
        {
           var dt1 = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(l => l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") >= minDate && l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") <= maxDate)
          .GroupBy(h => h.Field<string>("SQL_ID"))
          .Select(g =>
          {
              DataRow row2 = dtCurTopSQL.NewRow();
              row2["SQL_ID"] = g.Key;
              row2["CountAll"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("CountAll"));
              row2["CPU"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("CPU"));
              row2["Scheduler"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Scheduler"));
              row2["Activity"] = 0;
              return row2;
          }).CopyToDataTable();   
            ugTopSQL.DataSource = dt1;
        }

        else
        {
            ugTopSQL.DataSource = null;
        }                
}

private void bgwTA_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     getTA();
 }

try
{
    if (!bgwTA.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwTA.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error : Wait Event Reader!");
}
```

Here is the stacktraces of the errors;

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   konum: System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   konum: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow.get_ScrollCountInternal()
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow.Infragistics.Shared.ISparseArrayMultiItem.get_ScrollCount()
   konum: Infragistics.Shared.SparseArray.EnsureScrollCountCalculatedHelper(NodeExtended n)
   konum: Infragistics.Shared.SparseArray.EnsureScrollCountCalculated()
   konum: Infragistics.Shared.SparseArray.GetVisibleCount()
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.GetSpecialRowsHelper(List`1 list, Boolean top, UltraGridRow[] rowsToRecycle)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.CalcSpecialAndFixedRowsHelper(List`1& outSpecialRows, List`1& outFixedRows, Boolean top, UltraGridRow[] rowsToRecycle)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.EnsureSpecialAndFixedRowsCacheCalculated()
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.GetFixedRows(Boolean top)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowsCollection.HasFixedRows(Boolean top)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ViewStyleBase.get_Using_CreateRowsList_FixedRowsFeature()
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ViewStyleBase.RecreateRowList(RowScrollRegion rsr, Boolean syncWithCalcManager)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowScrollRegion.GetMaxScrollPosition(Boolean scrollToFill, Boolean ignoreScrollBoundsResolved)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowScrollRegion.EnsureScrollRegionFilled(Boolean calledFromRegenerateVisibleRows)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowScrollRegion.RegenerateVisibleRows(Boolean resetScrollInfo)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowScrollRegion.RegenerateVisibleRows()
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.DataAreaUIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridUIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawHelper(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Boolean clipText, Boolean forceDrawAsFocused, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics, Nullable`1 zoomFactor)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Size elementSize, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridUIElement.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The Second one ;

```
System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow.get_BaseHeight()
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.VisibleRow.GetDimensions(ColScrollRegion csr, VisibleRowDimensions dimensions, DimOriginBase originBase)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowColRegionIntersectionUIElement.PositionChildElements()
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowColRegionIntersectionUIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.DataAreaUIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridUIElement.VerifyChildElements(ControlUIElementBase controlElement, Boolean recursive)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawHelper(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Boolean clipText, Boolean forceDrawAsFocused, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics, Nullable`1 zoomFactor)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Size elementSize, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridUIElement.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: You can't access UI compoents such as MessageBox in a background worker as it will be on a different thread.  You need to use Invoke.  This explains a bit more:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired

Comment: Please show stacktrace of those exceptions

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith so, the grids and charts are UI here right ? If so, How can i call them after the bgw in seperate way? Also, you mean marshalling, right ?

Comment: @doctorcesar  You need to called invoke on them, as described in the article I linked to.  This will check if invoke is required (required only if on separate thread) and then call the method to update the UI element

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I read the article somehow i confused. Should i use invoke method inside of the function or after the background worker. If you wouldn't mind can you show me rewriting above code ?

Comment: i used to use 'backgroundworker', nowadays i use Tasks component as much as possible. spin up a new thread to get the database data while continue with other things, when it is finished, update the grid table...

Comment: @JoeWu  Is there any problem while you are using tasks like mine ?

Comment: not particular used on grid table, all other scenarios which involves 'heavy' calculation or longer time can be the candidate for Tasks. i haven't had any issue so far

Comment: So, Should i use tasks like this for above?  ; Task.Factory.StartNew(() => getTopSQL());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue where you seem to be trying to insert a key which already exists in the datatable, so this is not allowed. But I can't see your data so it is difficult to see the example problem.

You do however have another issue, which might not cause you a problem yet but it will.  That is that you can't make calls to UI elements (such as message Box) from a background worker.

The UI elements are always on the main thread where as a background worker could be on any thread so you will first need to check and then call a delegate to invoke.

But a better approach is to actually use the background worker events of

```
ProgressChanged
RunWorkerCompleted
```

These are executed on the same thread which started the backgroundworker.  So if you called this from your form then it will already be your UI thread.  So this makes life easier.

Your code is too long to repeat everything here, but I will give you an outline as to what is required.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += bgwTA_DoWork;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwTA_RunWorkerCompleted;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

private void bgwTA_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    dtTopSQL.Clear();
    odaTopSQL = new OracleDataAdapter(getTopSQLDetails, oradb);
    odaTopSQL.Fill(dtTopSQL);
    //etc

    e.Result = dt1;
}

private void bgwTA_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //Process was cancelled, need to clean up here
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        //Here was an error running the process. or the thread aborted.  
        //Need to raise errors and clean up here
        //If your process threw an exception, then it will be here                
    }
    else
    {
        //Everything worked OK, now we can update our UI elements
        //The Worker Completed thread will come back to the thread which called it.  Which, means if called from you main UI thread that you don't have to use invoke

        ugTopSQL.DataSource = (DataTable)e.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely perfect explanation all of the things. Thank you. I will try to implement in that way. Do i need to use the part  'worker.DoWork += bgwTA_DoWork;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwTA_RunWorkerCompleted;
' ? I just added bgw's using windows designer. The other question is, getting data from database to datatable in bgw shouldn't be problem right ?

Comment: These must be in your designer class.  Then you can just reuse what you have, and in your designer for the backgroundworker add the event "bgwTA_RunWorkerCompleted" to the "RunWorkerCompleted" in the pull down menu.   As long as your datatable is not access by any other element at the same time, then this will be OK.  An alternative is to create a new one in your OnWork event and pass that back as the result.